# Change and save XAML ResourceDictionary with PowerShell

Tags: xaml, powershell

I have file ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp">
    <Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <x:String x:Key="AppTitle">My App</x:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want change Background Property and AppTitle.

Output ResourceDictionary2.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp">
    <Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <x:String x:Key="AppTitle">My App 2</x:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I do it with Power Shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file as an XML file, change the values, then save it back to a file:

```psh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\ResourceDictionary.xaml'

$xml.ResourceDictionary.Style.Setter.Value = 'Green'
$xml.ResourceDictionary.'#text' = 'My App 2'

$xml.Save('C:\path\to\Output ResourceDictionary2.xaml')
```